# Why does my React button no longer link to an external site using anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I created a few buttons for my site in react. I used an anchor tag and everything was working fine but for some reason they no longer work. I don't remember making any changes and am confused as to why it stopped. Here's the button imported and used in the "About.js" file.

`<Button text="Join Our Discord" link="https://discord.gg/Zrk8kXfs" />`

And here is the where I created the button in "Button.js".

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Btn = styled.button`
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.text};
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.body};
  outline: none;
  border: none;

  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontsm};
  padding: 0.9rem 2.3rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  position: relative;

  &:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  &::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    border: 2px solid ${(props) => props.theme.text};
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }

  &:hover::after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    padding: 0.3rem;
  }
`;

const Button = ({ text, link }) => {
  return (
    <Btn>
      <a href={link} aria-label={text} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        {text}
      </a>
    </Btn>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `a` tag inside the `button`. It will confuse the screen reader for some browsers. Instead, you should use the tag as its functionality

I've updated your code:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledLink = styled.a`
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #efefef;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.body};
  outline: none;
  border: none;

  text-decoration: none;

  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontsm};
  padding: 0.9rem 2.3rem;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  position: relative;

  &:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  &::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    border: 2px solid ${(props) => props.theme.text};
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }

  &:hover::after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    padding: 0.3rem;
  }
`;

const Button = ({ text, link }) => {
  return (
    <StyledLink href={link} aria-label={text} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
      {text}
    </StyledLink>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using "Link" feature from react-router-dom, first, npm i react-router-dom

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link to="https://discord.gg/Zrk8kXfs">
  <Button>Join Our Discord</Button>
</Link>
```

Comment: No need to use `<Link />` from `react-router-dom` for external links. Use anchor tag, `<a />` is much better

Answer (score 0):

`To use a button as a link in React, wrap the button in an <a> tag or a Link component if using react router. The button will get rendered instead of the link and clicking on it will cause the browser to navigate to the specified page. App.js`

[https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-button-link#:~:text=To%20use%20a%20button%20as%20a%20link%20in,browser%20to%20navigate%20to%20the%20specified%20page.%20App.js](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-button-link#:%7E:text=To%20use%20a%20button%20as%20a%20link%20in,browser%20to%20navigate%20to%20the%20specified%20page.%20App.js)

```
<Link to="https://discord.gg/Zrk8kXfs">
  <Button text="Join Our Discord" />
</Link>
```

LOL, was literally typing the same thing as the above